# Insufficient register optimization of inlined class method

Tags: c++, optimization, visual-studio-2015

Why doesn't the compiler optimize the register usage of the inlined code from `Iterator::Incr` in the code sample shown below? (Visual Studio 2015, /O2 optimization settings)

When I am using the C++ code shown at the bottom of this post using a reference to the Iterator, the method `Iterator::Incr` **is inlined** inside `Interpolator::InterpolateFast`. However, the produced assembler code shows *memory* accesses to `Iterator::_rem`, although this class member variable could be placed inside a *register* for the inner loop for efficiency.

```
$LL2@Interpolat:
  00020 41 01 19     add     DWORD PTR [r9], ebx   ; memory access to Iterator::_rem (slow)
  00023 4d 63 01     movsxd  r8, DWORD PTR [r9]
  ...
  0003e 75 e0        jne     SHORT $LL2@Interpolat
```

When I am compiling the fast version where the iterator is copied, the assembler code places `Iterator::_rem` inside the processor registers and uses only one memory access to the array element itself.

```
$LL2@Interpolat:
; 699  :        _rem += _incr;
  00011 45 03 c2     add     r8d, r10d    ; Iterator::_rem placed inside registers (fast)
...
```

When using a reference to the Iterator class, it seems like the compiler would assume that the class is modified or accessed `InterpolateFast` (e.g., by a concurrent thread) and thus avoid register optimization.

How can I achieve an optimization of the inlined method using processor registers without copying the iterator?

```
typedef unsigned int BYTE;

class Iterator
{
public:
    Iterator() {}
    Iterator (const Iterator& it) :
        _rem (it._rem), _incr (it._incr) {}

    inline int Incr (const BYTE* &pSrc)
    {
        _rem += _incr;
        pSrc += _rem >> 16; 
        return _rem;
    }

private:
    int _rem;
    int _incr;
    friend class Interpolator;
};

class Interpolator
{
public:
    Interpolator (BYTE* p) : _p (p) {}
    int InterpolateFast (int len)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        const BYTE *p = _p;
        Iterator& it (_it);   // slow version, memory accesses to it._rem
        // Iterator it (_it); // fast version, registers optimized
        while (len--)
        {
            int rem = it.Incr (p);
            sum += p[0] * rem;
        }
        return sum;
    }

private:
    Iterator _it;
    const BYTE*    _p;
};

int main()
{
    BYTE arr[1000];
    Interpolator ip (arr);
    volatile int sum = ip.InterpolateFast (1000);
    return 0;
}
```

(Note that the code has been simplified for this post and does not have a meaningful function.)

Comment: doesn't compile. Can you post an MCVE?

Comment: It looks like a pointer aliasing problem - I don't know M$ compiler options but for me but try /Oa or /Ow and see if it helps for "slow" version. If yes then it could be possibly via code modification.

Comment: @RichardHodges: I updated the example.

Comment: @Anty: The MS VC++ compiler (VS2015) does not seem to support the compiler options /Oa /Ow ("ignoring unknown option"). I am compiling for x64 unmanaged C++ without .NET.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that at the end of the function, `_it` must have been modified by the calls to `Incr`.  With the copy, the only object that needs updating is destroyed, so the update is not externally visible.

Obviously the compiler *could* update the memory at the end of the loop, but that is tricky in the presence of early returns, or exceptions.  You and I can see that doesn't apply here, but the compiler may have got lost.

There is also the issue that if there are more complex calls inside the loop, the compiler will need to ensure `_it` is updated inside the loop.

The simplest workround is:

```
    Iterator it (_it); // fast version, registers optimized
    while (len--)
    {
        int rem = it.Incr (p);
        sum += p[0] * rem;
    }
    _it = it;  // ****** Added line
    return sum;
```

Incidentally, do you have timings that show that the memory access is slow?  After the first iteration, it will be in the L1 cache which is not much slower than registers. ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14505462/771073) suggests perhaps an additional 3-5 cycles, which might get overlapped with something else.)

Comment: The workaround with the copy constructor helps, but in my more complex original code (which I cannot post here), there is still one unnecessary memory access. I really would like solve the issue without using a workaround because I think the generated code will get better in that case.

The performance difference between the "slow" and "fast" versions is around 20% and will affect large parts of the codebase.

Comment: OK, you have measurements.  That's good.  Have you considered using the Intel compiler rather than the MSVC one? (Or possibly the VS2017 compiler.)  Other than that, it's either a matter of tweaking your C++ until the compiler generates the output you want, or writing some inline assembler.

Comment: It would be difficult to integrate a new compiler into our current build process. Inline assembler is not available when using 64 bit code -- you would have to setup an external assembler file. This is rather complicated because the InterpolateFast method is templated in my version.

I have still not given up hope for a special compiler flag, pragma etc. to optimize the code.

Comment: The Intel compiler is intended to be a drop in replacement for the MS one.  I think you are dreaming if there's going to be a pragma to help here.  Good luck though.